# Cannot get all entities under a kind in google datastore (using PHP)

Tags: php, google-app-engine, error-handling, google-cloud-datastore

I am new to google datastore, and I cannot get all entities under a kind. Here is my code.

```
use Google\Cloud\Datastore\DatastoreClient;
use Google\Cloud\Datastore\Query\Query;

function get_datastore_client(){

    # Your Google Cloud Platform project ID
    $projectId = 'my-project-id';

    # Instantiates a client
    $datastore = new DatastoreClient([
            'projectId' => $projectId
    ]);

    return $datastore;

}

function get_athlete_list(DatastoreClient $datastore){

    $transaction = $datastore->transaction();

    $query = $datastore->query()
        ->kind('Athlete')
        ->order('country');

    $result = $transaction->runQuery($query);

    $transaction->commit();

    return $result;

}

$datastore = get_datastore_client();
$all_athletes = get_athlete_list($datastore);
```

And when I ran this, I got empty result. Please help me to find out what is wrong.

**Update:**

I have tried using datastore instead of transaction and it didn't work, too. Function without transaction is below.

```
function get_athlete_list(DatastoreClient $datastore){

    $query = $datastore->query()
            ->kind('Athlete')
            ->order('country');

    $result = $datastore->runQuery($query);

    return $result;

}
```

And the strange thing is I can get one entity by its ID, function is below. I just cannot get all entities.

```
(This function works.)

function lookup_athlete(DatastoreClient $datastore, $athlete_id){

    $transaction = $datastore->transaction();

    $kind = 'Athlete';

    $athleteKey = $datastore->key($kind, $athlete_id);

    $athlete = $transaction->lookup($athleteKey);
    if(empty($athlete)){
        $transaction->rollback();
    }

    return $athlete;
}
```

So I think that maybe a setting issue, but I just cannot find out. I ran this in a compute engine instance and I have an APP engine instance runnning, according to this document, [Accessing the Cloud Datastore API from a Compute Engine instance](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/activate#accessing_the_short_product_name_api_from_a_compute_engine_instance).

**Update with solution:**

After hours of research, I found that in datastore library, "yield" is used instead of "return". This means the returned variable is just a generator object. And I didn't use the generator, so I cannot get the generated data. And that is why I got the issue. BTW, all my code is fine. :)

Thank you for all the replies.

Comment: did you try to run the query without the order clause?

Comment: Hi Michael, I tried that, and still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a PHP developer, but looks like you are using a transaction to load all records from an entity. This is not permitted because queries inside a transaction should be ancestor queries. My guess is that you are probably getting an exception/error indicating the same, but is being swallowed somewhere. If all you need to read the entities, you don't need a transaction, just use the datastore.

Comment: Thanks, but datastore didn't work for me either. I used transaction is because that I can use it to get a single entity.